# Datadog stop gets Jenkins events, restart solve the issue

Tags: jenkins, datadog

we use Jenkins 2.60.1 , with Datadog plugin 0.6.1

after first installation all works well , but after some time we stop get events in Datadog. restart Jenkins solve the issue.

any idea ?

Comment: What is your system resources? Check for ram and cache when datadog stops sending events, it might be system is hanging

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I just find out that me second Jenkins - 2.46.3 has the same problem , both machines are AWS machines c4.8xlarge , don't see any load on them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem - https://github.com/DataDog/jenkins-datadog-plugin/issues/101

current Datadog version 0.6.1. has a bug , after change the Jenkins main config ( any change , not related to Datadog configuration) it stop works.

**I downgrade it to 0.5.7 and it works OK**

Comment: 0.6.2 is out and fixes this issue: https://github.com/DataDog/jenkins-datadog-plugin/issues/101